# Symfony 4 built-in web server how to change log level?

Tags: symfony4, php-7.2

I just created a new Symfony 4 project based on the skeleton.
I can start the built-in web server with:

`php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public`

But when I navigate to the root page of the website, I get a bunch of debug messages.

*In other projects I don't see those debug messages, how do I control the log level?*

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000
>   Document root is /Users/lucwollants/Workspaces/2dotstwice/gvq/gvq-api/public
>   Press Ctrl-C to quit.
>   2018-05-02T07:23:18+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
>   2018-05-02T07:23:18+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest".
>   2018-05-02T07:23:18+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
>   2018-05-02T07:23:18+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
>   2018-05-02T07:23:18+00:00 [debug] Listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest" stopped propagation of the event "kernel.request".
>   2018-05-02T07:23:18+00:00 [debug] Listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\ResolveControllerNameSubscriber::onKernelRequest" was not called for event "kernel.request".
>   2018-05-02T07:23:18+00:00 [debug] Listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest" was not called for event "kernel.request".
>   2018-05-02T07:23:18+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
>   2018-05-02T07:23:18+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelResponse".
>   2018-05-02T07:23:18+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse".
>   2018-05-02T07:23:18+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
>   2018-05-02T07:23:18+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
>   2018-05-02T07:23:18+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
>   [Wed May  2 09:23:18 2018] 127.0.0.1:51666 [404]: /

Answer (score 0):

look in your composer.json and see if you have this under any of the dependencies

"symfony/debug-pack": "*"

also log level can be changed by setting the SHELL_VERBOSITY environment variable

this explains it more [Logging (Symfony Docs)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html)